# Find files by the length of filename

Tags: command-line, find, filenames

I want to find all files by length of the file names.

For example if I want to find files of length 1, such as `a.go`, `b.go`.

I put:

```
grep '.\{1\}' file
```

But this does not work. What command can I use to find files by file name length?

Comment: `a.go` is a filename of length 4.  `a` is a filename of length 1.  This is Unix, not DOS where the name and extension were separate and an implicit `.` was always part of the filename.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`grep` looks for patterns in the contents of the files.  If you want to look at the *names* of the files, you can just use a shell glob (if you want to consider only filenames in the current directory):

```
echo ?.go
```

(By the way, it's the shell that evaluates the glob, not the `echo` command.)

If you want to look in directories recursively, starting with the current directory, the tool to use is `find`:

```
find . -name '?.go'
```

(Note that you have to quote the pattern to prevent the shell from evaluating it as a glob before `find` gets invoked.)

Comment: This will also find directories that also match the pattern '?.go'.

Comment: @slm, directories are one of many types of files, the OP didn't specify what type of files he was after.

Answer (score 21):

If you just want to find the filenames, you can use the following command:

```
find -exec basename '{}' ';' | egrep '^.{100,}$'
```

That will run `find`, pulling off the name of the file or directory using `basename` and then look for any filename or directory name that is at least 100 characters.  If you wanted to find a filename of an exact length, use `{100}` instead of `{100,}`.

If you want to find the filenames including the path, do this:

```
find | egrep '/[^/]{100,}$'
```

This will return the filename including the relative path to where you ran the find command.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, `grep` searches through the *contents* of files, it will not search for file names. For that you want `find`. It does not have an option to set the filename length but you can parse it's output to get what you want. Here are some examples that I run in a directory containing the following files:

```
$ tree
.
├── a
├── ab
├── abc
├── abcd
└── dir
    ├── a
    ├── ab
    ├── abc
    └── abcd
```

Searching for files in this directory returns:

```
$ find . -type f | sort
./a
./ab
./abc
./abcd
./dir/a
./dir/ab
./dir/abc
./dir/abcd
```

So, to find the files with a length of X, we will need to remove the path and match only the characters after the last `/`:

```
 $ find . -type f | grep -P '/.{3}$'
```

The `sed` command just removes the `./`. The `-P` flag activates Perl Compatible Regular Expressions which are needed for `{n}` which is a PCRE thing and the `$` means "match the end of the string".

You could also simply do this:

```
find . -type f | grep -P '/...$'
```

That's fine for small numbers typing 15 dots to match filenames of length 15 is not very efficient.

Finally, if you want to ignore the extension and match only the file's name, do this (as @slm suggested):

```
find . -type f | grep -P '/.{1}\.'
```

However, this will also find files like `a.bo.go`. This is better if your filenames can contain more than one `.` :

```
find . -type f | grep -P '/.{1}\.[^.]+$'
```

---

NOTE: The solution above assumes that you have relatively sane filenames that don't contain new line characters etc. It will also count not ignore spaces in filenames when calculating the length which might not be what you want. If either of these is a problem, let me know and I'll update my answer.

Comment: `{x,y}` is also in standard extended regexps (as in `grep -E`), it's not perl (let alone PCRE) specific. Standard BREs also have `\{x,y\}` (added there before `{x,y}` was added in EREs)

Comment: `find . -type f | grep -P '/.{3}$'` also matches on `./x/y`

Answer (score 2):

If you have GNU find, you can just do:

```
find . -type f -regextype 'posix-basic' -iregex '.*/.\{1\}\.go$'
./a.go
./dir1/b.go
./dir2/subdir1/subdir2/a.go
```

---

```
find . -type f -regextype 'egrep' -iregex '.*/.{2}\.go$'
./ab.go
./dir1/zx.go
./dir2/subdir1/subdir2/xo.go
```

---

you can use different `-regextype` based on your need.

> valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘awk’, ‘egrep’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’,
> ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’,
> ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify but if the files are within a directory structure you can use `find` to locate files that are length 1, with the help of `grep`:

```
$ find . -type f  | grep -P '/.{1}\.'
```

#### Example

```
$ find . -type f  | grep -P '/.{1}\.' | head -10
./util-linux-2.19/include/c.h
./88366/a.bash
./89186/a.bash
./89563/b.txt
./89563/a.txt
./89563/c.txt
./89563/d.txt
./91734/2.c
./91734/4.c
./91734/1.c
```

Comment: On MacOS X, use egrep and remove the -P option

Comment: @BartKummel - actually on OSX I use `ggrep`: http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/09/install-gnu-grep-on-mac-osx.html. Also realize that this Q was not tagged as OSX so the use of `grep` is apt.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this.

```
find . -type f -name "?.go"
```

So if you put two "?" then you are looking for file names with two characters and the extension.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use a glob in `find` command, you should use quotes, such as:

```
find /var/log -iname "*.err"
```

for your case use:

```
find yourpath -type f -a -name "?.go"
```

You should replace `yourpath` with your real path.

- `-a` means "and"
- `-type f` means you are looking for regular files only.
- `?` in your query means one character such as DOS if you recall.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working solution using `ls` although it's a bit silly. It basically creates a string consisting of question marks that correspond to the desired file name length and then allows for shell expansion of that as a wildcard, giving the resulting filenames to the `ls` command (and whatever switches you supply to it ahead of the filenames, of course - e.g., `-l`):

```
# Tested on CentOS 7

###############################
# With a fixed length (of 32) #
###############################
ls $(for i in {1..32};do echo -n '?';done)

##########################
# With a variable length #
##########################
# Set the filename length (or get it from elsewhere)
declare -x filename_len=32

# The following command can be employed
ls $(eval "for i in {1..$filename_len};do echo -n '?';done")

# Or, because eval is considered evil, the better alternative
ls $(seq -s ' ' 1 $filename_len | sed 's/[[:digit:]]\+ \?/?/g')

# Many other approaches can be used to do something similar
# (e.g., perl, etc...) to generate the question marks
ls $(perl -e 'print "?"x$ENV{filename_len}')
# If you're bothered by the quotes in the above around the question
# mark, since no interpolation is needed, you can change:
# "?" to '"'?'"'  - in this case, I'd leave the quotes for clarity.

unset filename_len
```

One caveat here is that the resulting list of filenames could be longer than the shell allows and that is something you'd have to consider. That's why a `find`/`xargs` approach is generally best if the number of files is unbounded or unknown.

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, to find regular files whose name has one and only one character excluding the extension, or in other words one character before the first dot if any:

```
find . '(' -name '[!.]' -o -name '[!.].*' ')' -type f
```

For three characters:

```
find . '(' -name '[!.][!.][!.]' -o -name '[!.][!.][!.].*' ')' -type f
```

You get the gist.

Note that with those, for a file called `.v2.tar.gz` the extension is `v2.tar.gz` and the rest is empty (of length 0).

With `zsh`, you can also do:

```
set -o extendedglob
print -rC1 -- **/[^.](#c3)(|.*)(ND.)
```

Where the `(#cx[,y])` extendedglob is the equivalent of regexp `{x[,y]}` to match from `x` to `y` of the preceding thing (or exactly `x` if `,y` is omitted) , `**/` is any level of subdirectories, `N` for `N`ullglob, `D` for `D`otglob, `.` the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f`.

Answer (score -3):

`ls ?.*` should give you desired results.

Comment: welcome to Unix.SE.  It's unfortunately not useful to add answers to old questions that already have lots of good answers.  (Unless there's a new better way to solve an old problem, or you have a better solution than any of the old answers.)  If you want to answer some questions, look at the new questions on the front page.

Comment: `ls: cannot access '?.*': No such file or directory`