# List files recursively in Linux CLI with path relative to the current directory, max 250 char

Tags: files, find, recursive

I'm trying to list all the files with names no longer than 250 characters (including the directory it is part of, from the relative path my command is inside).

[I've seen a similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245698/list-files-recursively-in-linux-cli-with-path-relative-to-the-current-directory)  , but that will only list the files recursively.

Any idea on how to modify script to only show files with names no longer than 250 characters (including the relative path)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find files by the length of filename](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93111/find-files-by-the-length-of-filename)

Comment: When I use this: find . -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '.{251,}' ! -type d It shows: 

find: unrecognized: -regextype 

I also tried : find . ! -path "$(printf %251s | tr ' ' '?')*" 

Unfortunately, for some reason, when i calculate the output, they are only 220 characters...

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `find`:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '.{253,}' ! -type d
```

(that prints a `./` prefix which is not included in the 250 count).

With `zsh`:

```
setopt extendedglob # if not already in your ~/.zshrc
printf '%s\n' **/*~?(#c251,)(D^/)
```

That's all paths recursively (`**/*`) including hidden ones (`(D)`), but not (`^`) those of type *directory* (`/`), except (`~`) those that match `?(#c251,)`, that is that contain 251 characters or more.

POSIXly:

```
find . ! -path "$(printf %253s | tr ' ' '?')*" ! -type d
```

(note that there's nothing on Unix that guarantees that file names are made of valid characters. Except for the `zsh` one, those solutions may also report files whose path contain sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters (adding `-path '*'` may help excluding those). If you want to match on the number of *bytes* as opposed to number of *characters* in your locale, you can fix the locale to `C` with `export LC_ALL=C`).

Comment: POSIX part is tricky, +1!

Comment: When I use this:

find . -regextype posix-extended ! -regex '.{251,}' ! -type d

It shows:
find: unrecognized: -regextype

I also tried :

find . ! -path "$(printf %251s | tr ' ' '?')*"

Unfortunately, for some reason, when i calculate the output, they are only 220 characters....

Comment: @tuckker. The first one requires _GNU_ `find`. Yours is probably `busybox` find. 220 is not longer than 250, so by your requirements, those files should be listed. Update your question if that's not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly:

```
$ find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for f do
      [ "${#f}" -le 252 ] &&
      printf "%s\n" "$f"
    done
' sh {} +
```

POSIX defined [${#parameter}](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) as the length in characters of value parameter, but the behaviour may varies in some shells. `bash`, `zsh`, `yash` count characters, `dash` count bytes. `ksh93` has a random bug depends on its implementation.

Comment: Note that for paths that contain multi-byte characters or sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters, the behaviour varies across `sh` implementations (`${#f}` counts bytes in ksh and dash and characters in bash, zsh and yash; yash chokes on invalid characters).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Is it a weird behaviour since when POSIX specified that `${#parameter}` is the length in characters of the value of parameter?

Comment: Yes, it's a bug in those shells. [That was discussed on the austin group ml not so long ago](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.standards.posix.austin.general/9972/focus=10040). I was partly wrong for ksh above. `ksh93 -c 'echo "${#1}"' sh $'\ue9\xe9'` gives me 19, but that's a random bug in ksh93. With `mksh`, it gives me `3` but `2` with `mksh -o utf8-mode`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: I have ksh version `sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01` both in Debian and OSX. The one in OSX return 2, but Debian return 53 for your example.